# logger.debug() NoSuchMethodError Spring-Boot with Elasticsearch client 5.5.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I tried to upgrade the elasticsearch client from 1.x to the current version 5.5.2 (only the transport layer) and after fixing all the API-changes I'm having a major problem with the logger-bridges.

As told in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_using_another_logger.html), I added the necessary dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.24</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I'm still getting the following exception (in detail):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.debug(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:203)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:129)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:265)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:130)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:116)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:106)
at net.my-local-stuff.nia.NiaApplication.esClient(NiaApplication.java:168)
```

Before that upgrade I was having logback as the logger, and it is stilled pulled by the slf4j facade in my own code (obviously it doesn't get pulled inside elasticsearch's code).

In case anyone wants to see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/frickm/dcd9b5266d462c9569ecebb2b8613ca9) for the dependency tree. To me it looks as if all necessary dependencies are there.

Everything that is written about the logging-thing seems to end up in a classes that are not found (while I, somehow, get a logger instance but this logger-instance doesn't have all methods . :-().

Help is very much appreciated
fricke

Comment: Did you get anything? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: no, I couldn't figure it out so I stayed with version 1.7.

Comment: I faced the same issue recently. According to gist there is an old version (2.1) of `log4j-api` in your classpath. You have to declare dependency on `log4j-api 2.8.2` explicitly and make sure there is no other versions in classpath.